# Resize efi partition on Ubuntu / Mac system on Mac Air

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

My Ubuntu and Mac both boot perfectly on my Mac Air. I have about 240 GB for each.  But my Ubuntu tells me my efi partition only has 6mb of remaining space.  In addition, my Ubuntu sometimes freezes after which I'm not sure if this is related.

Anyway, would I need to resize my efi partition with Mac?  I'm running el capitan.  Everything concerning booting is running perfectly with ReFind, so I don't want to change too much. I'd just like to dedicate a little more space to my EFI partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macs normally come with [EFI System Partitions (ESPs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) of about 100 MiB, which is plenty big enough for most purposes. (I recommend making them bigger for reasons related to EFI driver bugs, but that's not an issue here.) If you're seeing just ~6 MiB of free space on your ESP (with a mount point of `/boot/efi`), then something is wrong. I recommend you [discover what's consuming your disk space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219706/whats-consuming-hdd-space) and delete or move anything that should not be there. Normally, you'll have an `EFI/ubuntu` partition with GRUB and/or an `EFI/refind` partition with rEFInd, neither of which should consume more than a few megs of space. There's also likely to be an empty `EFI/APPLE` directory and possibly an `EFI/tools` directory with two or three `.efi` binaries.

That said, I can't help but wonder if you might have mis-reported the problem. If you have a separate `/boot` partition, it often fills up with kernel updates; see these bug reports:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades/+bug/1357093
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1465050

The Linux `/boot` partition is *not* the same as the ESP. If this is the problem, then doing a `sudo apt-get autoremove` *should* clear it, provided there isn't an issue with the package system that prevents removal of the old packages.